# A PAC-like analogue for 1-class classification?

Tags: lg.learning, machine-learning

This is more of a philosophical question -- I am looking for a reasonable mathematical formulation of 1-class learning.

In the PAC model, it's very natural to formulate our demand on the learner: produce a hypothesis with low generalization error.

What might be a reasonable formalization of 1-class learning? This may also be called "anomaly detection": in the training phase, the learner only gets to see positive ("normal") examples, but in the test phase he needs to predict whether a given new example is positive ("normal") or negative (an anomaly). The formal details are quite open-ended -- what's a reasonable assumption on the training sample (generated from some distribution, etc)? What's a reasonable success criterion?

Comment: Did you find a theoretical justification for this question yet?

Comment: Well, we wrote a [paper](http://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/~karyeh/anomaly.pdf) that takes a step in this direction, but I am not totally satisfied with this approach. Would be very curious to hear feedback/ideas!

Answer (score 7):

I think there is a model called "Learning from Positive Examples (Only)" or you can additionally allow unlabeled data (I don't remember the details).  A search for these terms should bring up various papers and models.  [Here](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~elkan/posonly.pdf) is one.

Comment: Thanks, Lev! (For some reason this requires answers of at least 15 chars)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, then Valiant's seminal paper "[A theory of the learnable](http://www.cse.iitk.ac.in/users/chitti/thesis/references/valiant.pdf)" (Communications of the ACM 27(11), 1134-1142) defines a model you are looking for, if you exclude queries to ORACLE and stick with EXAMPLE (which provides the learner with a positive instance; however, see details of the definition in the paper). I believe it was only afterwards that this model got transformed into PAC with both positive and negative instances returned by such an oracle. (Note that, e.g., the algorithm for learning k-CNF defined in this paper does not use ORACLE, only EXAMPLE.)